# Identify impure functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am learning Clojure and functional programming in general (coming from python). In Clojure it is possible to make impure functions, since you can use slurp and other means of input. Is there a way to easily identify impure functions in Clojure, or is it practice to just keep those functions in a separate section of the code?

Comment: Not really, no. How would you define "impure function", anyway? Is [`memoize`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize) impure? What about a function *returned* by `memoize`? Or a referentially transparent function that uses [transients](http://clojure.org/reference/transients) internally?

Comment: Clojure is not a pure FP language, like for example Haskell. If this important to you, then Clojure is not the right choice.

Comment: @MichielBorkent: being pure is not important to me, I just thought it would be interesting if one could separate pure and impure sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a common [convention](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards) to end a function name with a bang (eg. `swap!`) where that function is not safe for use inside an STM transaction. This includes IO and many types of side-effect, so there is some overlap here with impurity, however, many impure functions are also entirely safe.

Comment: Please reword the "not safe for use within the STM" part, because swap is part of the STM ;-) it's totally safe, it just has controlled side efects.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt The wording is already very similar to the phrase in the Library Coding Standard: "Use the bang! only for things not safe in an STM transaction." So I'm not sure how I can improve it.

Comment: I really don't want to see people avoiding using `swap!` from within `dosync` blocks because they think it will be "unsafe". We have to be careful about leaving statements on sites like this that start rumours like that. You could choose an example that actually is unsafe to use inside the STM while making it clear that this is not the case for all functions who's name ends in !

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt As I understand it, `swap!` may execute multiple times in a `dosync` block and may modify the atom multiple times, which is not really what people want. Is that not correct?

Comment: That is not correct. All interactions with agents and atoms are held until the transaction commits and are sent to the agents and atoms exactly one. With the special case that they are sent zero times of the transaction errors out. They are guaranteed to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, I will take this up with the authors of a certain book. If they are going to put it into print I would expect it to be correct.

Comment: If they simply drop the word "only" from that sentence It would be a very useful and accurate way to learn.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I mean the "Clojure Programming" book. Anyway, so I've tried this out and `swap!` does not behave as you claim. It still executes when the transaction errors out. Unlike `alter` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, there is no way to identify whether a function produces side effects or not (due to Rice's Theorem). So, it is probably impossible to distinguish pure functions from impure functions. Of course, there might be a way to check whether a function is definitely impure at a syntactic level, but I doubt this would actually help in practice.